# Select statement returning no rows

Tags: mysql, database, select, rows, resultset

I was asked to write an MYSQL code that returns data from specific dates (2003-2005 December only)from my database. I, however, cannot figure out why I am getting no data returned. The code I am using is below. I tried to use the BETWEEN clause but I still get no data returned. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
select 
paymentDate, amount, discounted
From 
payments
where 
paymentDate >= 2003-12-01 and paymentDate <= 2003-12-31
and paymentDate >= 2004-12-01 and paymentDate <= 2004-12-31
and paymentDate >= 2005-12-01 and paymentDate <= 2005-12-31
Order by paymentDate;
```

Comment: I suspect the date field may have a different format. I would suggest selecting a single row with only the `paymentDate` to confirm the format.

Comment: Additionally to @MattCan 's suggestion. Try to put date in quotes like this paymentDate >= '2003-12-01'.

Comment: 2003-12-01 = 1990. Perhaps you're thinking of '2003-12-01'

Answer (score 0):

Because the `paymentDate` may not be simultaneously in December of each of those years.
Instead connect each of the December conditional statements with `or`.
Also I included ANSI syntax for the dates, i.e. `date '2003-12-01'`

```
where 
(paymentDate >= date '2003-12-01' and paymentDate <= date '2003-12-31'
 or paymentDate >= date '2004-12-01' and paymentDate <= date '2004-12-31'
 or paymentDate >= date '2005-12-01' and paymentDate <= date '2005-12-31')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Vorsprung durch Technik but it is still returning no data. I am also certain that the table does contain data for December in all of those years.

Comment: You're welcome. I made an edit to my answer. Would you try that out?

Comment: Yes, success! That was the issue. Funny thing is I tried that but I think I had the DATE in the wrong place. Thank you for your help.